# openxlsx:: loadWorkbook / saveWorkbook throws errors and messes sheets formatting

Tags: r, openxlsx

When trying to load xlsx file to R, using openxlsx::loadWorkbook

```
ExcelFile <- loadWorkbook(ReportFilePath) #ReportFilePath is a character variable containing path to the file
```

R returns warning:

```
In sprintf("<Relationship Id=\"rId4\" Type=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/externalLink\" Target=\"externalLinks/externalLink1.xml\"/>",  :one argument not used by format '<Relationship Id="rId4" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/externalLink" Target="externalLinks/externalLink1.xml"/>'
```

The file contains multiple sheets, with lots of formatting, hidden ranges, formulas, etc. It is a pretty complex xlsx file. The file does not contain any connections to external data, but it has navigation panel with hyperlinks to sheets within the document.

After saving the workbook:

```
saveWorkbook(ExcelFile, ReportFilePath, overwrite = TRUE)
```

I see that most of text formatting is removed, ranges that were hidden are now unhidden and vice versa. Additionally, R returns warning message:

```
Warning messages:
1: In .self$setColWidths(i) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In .self$setColWidths(i) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In .self$setColWidths(i) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In .self$setColWidths(i) : NAs introduced by coercion
5: In .self$setColWidths(i) : NAs introduced by coercion
6: In .self$setColWidths(i) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I reviewed the documentation of openxlsx package and googled for the warning, but it seems that there is no obvious solution to this. What can I do to ensure that workbook is successfully loaded and saved? What are the root causes of these warnings?

Comment: Are you using the most recent version of openxlsx? If updating doesn't fix the problem then you could try loading single-sheet versions of the workbook to isolate the sheet that's causing issues.

Comment: @BluVoxe I checked and I am using the latest version of the package. I also checked how eliminating sheets will work to determine which sheet is a problem, but even when I removed all existing sheets and created a new one with some random data, no formatting, the issue still persists. When I recreated the same in the completely new file, there is no problem with loading the workbook. Very strange.

Comment: Interesting... In that case my best guess is that it's something to do with the time that your original workbook was created, maybe Excel used to use some kind of different formatting that openxlsx forgot to account for. Unfortunately I've found there's often a bit of troubleshooting to do with openxlsx, but it's very powerful if you can get it working. Without seeing your actual workbook I don't think I can offer any more help though, sorry!

Comment: I figured it out that there where some connections (Excel -> Data -> Connections) to files that no longer existed (and sheets with these connections were removed some time ago, but they were still appearing in the list of connections) and after removing these connections, R is not throwing errors at least, but it still resets the formatting and messes ranges hiding.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this problem, and have no idea what the cause is. My solution was to break all external links to the excel file and this fixed the problem.

File -> info -> edit links -> break links

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. It seems that solution is simple, and perhaps the problem is not related to openxlsx. I found the potential solution by chance, when checking formulas/name manager, I found a remaining table with external connection, which was not screened by regular methods to find external links. In my case, it did solve the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).